# How to get a geopandas map to appear in a wxpython window

Tags: python, matplotlib, wxpython, geopandas

I have adapted some code that I had previously used to display a matplotlib graph in a wxPython window so that it displays a geopandas' map in a wxPython window. The map does display, but when I close the window, the application doesn't terminate. I'm using python 3.6, wxpython 4.0.1 on Mint 19.2.

Here is some example code that demonstrates the issue:

```
import wx
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
from matplotlib.backends.backend_wxagg import FigureCanvasWxAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import geopandas as gpd

class MapCanvasPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self, -1, self.figure)
        self.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.sizer.Add(self.canvas, 1, wx.LEFT | wx.TOP | wx.GROW)
        self.SetSizer(self.sizer)
        self.Fit()

        # Read GeoDataFrame from file
        self.uk_data = gpd.read_file("gadm36_GBR.gpkg")

    def drawMap(self):
        self.axes.clear()
        self.uk_plot = self.uk_data.plot(ax=self.axes, color='white', edgecolor='black')
        self.uk_plot.axis('off')
        self.canvas.draw()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = wx.Frame(None, title='Test Map')
    panel = MapCanvasPanel(frame)
    panel.drawMap()
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

When I step through the code in the PyCharm debugger, a second window (that is like the window that matplotlib displays in interactive mode) appears. When I close that second window the program does terminate. If I run the program normally, the second window doesn't appear, but I suspect it may have been created and is hidden and that is what is stopping the program from closing. How do I get my program to terminate properly?

Note: the Geopackage file used by the example code was downloaded by selecting 'United Kingdom' on https://gadm.org/download_country_v3.html and then clicking the 'Geopackage' link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the line:

```
matplotlib.use('WXAgg')
```

By removing it, your code should behave as expected (by displaying the UK map on a `wx.Frame` and returning correctly when closing this window).

See the matplotlib gallery about [Embedding Matplotlib in graphical user interfaces](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/#embedding-matplotlib-in-graphical-user-interfaces), there is some code examples with wxPython (which doesn't use `matplotlib.use` either).

*(tested on Python `3.6`, wx `4.0.1` and matplotlib `2.2.3`)*